# Modify Powershell script to to copy from multiple sources to a single destination using Robocopy

Tags: powershell, robocopy

want to write a script (preferably in PowerShell) to copy (robocopy) files from multiple directories to a single destination. I am able to do this for a single source directory. But need help to modify it to copy from multiple locations. Here's the skeletal script:

```
Robocopy $Root $Dest /E /XX /COPYALL
```

Edit: Solved using multiple variables to store multiple dir and "Foreach loop" command as follows

```
$Origin1=ABC
$Origin2=DEF
```

.
.

`$ALLOri=$Origin1,$Origin2` ...

```
ForEach ($i in $ALLOri) {robocopy $i $dest /E /XX /COPYALL}
```

Comment: Look here: https://serverfault.com/questions/272919/copy-multiple-folders-to-a-single-destination-with-robocopy

Comment: I want to be able to copy directories of my choice which do not follow any specific pattern as in the link. (Also, this is like my first ever powershell script so apologies if I misunderstand or don't understand something)